# Understanding lattice matching of graphene on silver (111) crystal surface and meaning of the √3 x √3 lattice?

Tags: crystal-structure, carbon-allotropes, crystallography, silver

Figure 1 in Ivor Lončarić and Vito Despoja, Phys. Rev. B 90, 075414 [Benchmarking van der Waals functionals with noncontact RPA calculations on graphene-Ag(111)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.90.075414) (available in [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264829201_Benchmarking_van_der_Waals_functionals_with_noncontact_RPA_calculations_on_graphene-Ag111)) shows a schematic of the graphene structure on what I believe is a silver (111) surface.

The caption reads:

> FIG. 1. (Color online) Geometry of the supercell used for our vdW DFT calculations. Upper part: 2 × 2 graphene lattice matched to √3 × √3 Ag(111) lattice. Lower part: Geometry of the supercell in perpendicular direction.

What exactly is a "√3 × √3 Ag(111) lattice" and how exactly does the square root of three come in to this?

[image: supercell 2 × 2 graphene lattice matched to √3 × √3 Ag(111) lattice]

Comment: companion question: [Silver (111) surface structure, and is bulk structure body-center or face-center cubic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/116617/16035)

Comment: The $\sqrt{3}$ is the distance shown as black lines between every other C atom (assuming bond length is one unit). Twice this is the _equivalent_ length between the Ag atoms  shown as silver/grey. So I'm assuming this is what they mean by lattice matching?

Comment: @porphyrin I'll take a look based on that, thanks!

Comment: See http://ww2.sljus.lu.se/staff/anders/Compressed/Notation_Edvin.pdf for a general overview (googled 'silver 111 surface reconstruction').

Comment: @JonCuster I've been checking that out, it seems everything I need to know is in there; bottom left of slide #22 suggests Ag(111) has a vertical reconstruction but the lateral positions are same as truncated bulk, slide #16 and Masel's *Principles of Adsorption and Reaction on Solid Surfaces* helps me understand the notation for graphene's orientation, and slide #21's illustration of fcc vs hcp notation preempts my next graphene on Ag(111) question! *Nice find, thank you!*

Comment: Good news! Classic surface science seems to have faded away if late. Recall that most of the original surface reconstruction information was from techniques like LEED that gave relative symmetry and rotation, but we had to wait for AFM to see actual atom positions.

Comment: @porphyrin I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Is it possible for you to post an answer and include at least a crude drawing? I don't know what "distance shown as black lines between every other C atom" means, nor what "equivalent length between the Ag atoms" means on a fcc(111) surface. Can you just take my image and overlay a few arrows? Thanks!

Comment: Start at the left bottom most blue atom (crossed by 2 black lines), go north by 1 atom and north east  by 1 atom. The distance as the crow flies is $\sqrt{3}$ times bond length, i.e. length of black line connecting atoms. Now look at underlying Ag atoms; twice this length is equivalent length in this lattice so I guessed that this is connection between lattices and why one fits over the other. This could be rubbish, however, as I'm not an expert in surface science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Root 3" or "$\sqrt{3}$" or "$\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}$" are slang for the Wood's notation ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction#Notation_of_reconstructions), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlayer#Wood's_notation)) $ \left( \sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}\right)R30$, a commonly occurring configuration of one hexagonal 2D lattice with respect another.

In this example the substrate is the (111) face of silver. Since it is [face-centered cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system) with lattice constant of about 4.08 Angstroms the (111) surface is hexagonal with a lattice constant 4.08 / $\sqrt{2}$ = 2.88 Angstroms.

The figure caption says "2 × 2 graphene lattice matched to √3 × √3 Ag(111) lattice."

The annotation in the OP's drawing copied below shows solid arrows for the Ag(111) lattice vectors the dashed arrows are rotated by 30 degrees and $\sqrt{3}$ longer, and they match the periodicity of a $2 \times 2$ graphene cell.

The lattice constant of *free graphene* is about 2.46 Angstroms and double that is 4.92. Compared to $\sqrt{3}$ times 2.88 = 4.99 Angstroms it's a fairly good lattice match.

[image: 2x2 graphene as root3 of Ag(111)]