# Why does FCC crystalline forms form hexagonal crystalline structures during CVD?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, crystal-structure, metallurgy, crystallography

During the CVD process, Copper and Nickel which are both Face Centered Cubic crystalline structures are used as substrates for shaping hexagonal atomic structures such as graphene and hexagonal Boron-Nitride. Why is it that these form hexagonal atomic structures when they themselves aren't hexagonal?

Comment: But they **are** hexagonal, if you look at them sideways.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite grasp what you mean. Do you have a visual representation?

Comment: Fcc and hcp structures are similar stacking (fcc you need to look along the 111 body diagonal - a classic issue with the cubic conventional cell).

Comment: @AndiIacob for that check [my answer to *Silver (111) surface structure, and is bulk structure body-center or face-center cubic?*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/153327/16035) Basically the "centered" lattices (fcc, bcc in 3D, centered rectangular in 2D) are contrived to be human friendly; the actual primitive unit cells are much smaller and oblique, and the 3D ones result in horizontal hexagonal planes when the "cubes" are stood up on their corners.

Comment: @uhoh so this means there are no modifications needed to the substrate correct? Om effect, any FCC could theoretically be used to make hexagonal shapes? And BCC as well?

Comment: @AndiIacob The internal fcc(111) planes for a simple metal will generally have a hexagonal arrangement, and a flat fcc(111) surface there certainly can be hexagonal as well. However sometimes clean, annealed fcc(111) (as well as other) surfaces have [surface reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction)s, the most famous being Au(111) 22×√3  herringbone reconstruction, (amenable to googling). I don't know about BCC but I can find out in a day or so. Si isn't simple fcc, but the Si(111) surface has a very interesting 7×7 reconstruction.

Comment: @AndiIacob you can also try the hex face of a hexagonal crystal like [hexagonal boron nitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_nitride) (as you've mentioned) or [hexagonal silicon carbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_carbide), or even cleaved [HOPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_oriented_pyrolytic_graphite).

Answer (score 4):

> [Ivan Neretin] But they are hexagonal, if you look at them sideways. –

> [OP] Sorry I dont quite grasp what you mean. Do you have a visual representation?

Here is the [visual](http://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/crystalstructure/structures/fcc/fcc_jsmol.php).

[image]

> [Jon Custer] Fcc and hcp structures are similar stacking (fcc you need to look along the 111 body diagonal - a classic issue with the cubic conventional cell).

Yes, both may be constructed by stacking hexagonal layers, either in an ABABA.. (hexagonal close packing hcp) or an ABCABCA.. (face-centered cubic fcc) fashion.

Comment: Nice visual there!

Comment: I've linked to your answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/153327/16035) +1